# My distance in miles calculation seems wrong in swift 3

Tags: swift3, xcode8.2

I have a user's current location and a particular location. I am trying to get distance in miles. my distance in miles seems wrong, I got 1.2 miles on my app, then I checked the miles in google map. I got 2.1 miles on google map. Here is my code, I am not sure why my code is not accurate. Please help.

```
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    map.delegate = self
    map.userTrackingMode = MKUserTrackingMode.follow

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    // set location
    let latitude: CLLocationDegrees = 32.5850
    let longitude: CLLocationDegrees = -85.4904
    let latDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.05
    let lonDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.05
    let span: MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: latDelta, longitudeDelta: lonDelta)
    let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinates, span: span)

    map.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    // add annotation 
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.title = "1100 S College St"
    annotation.coordinate = coordinates

    map.addAnnotation(annotation)

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let userLocation: CLLocation = locations[0]
    let latitude = userLocation.coordinate.latitude
    let longitude = userLocation.coordinate.longitude

    let location1 = CLLocation(latitude: 32.5850, longitude: -85.4904) // set location

    let location2 = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude) // user's current location

    let distanceInMeters : CLLocationDistance = location1.distance(from: location2) // distance in meters

    let distanceInMiles = distanceInMeters/1609.344  // distance in miles

    let roundUp = String(format:"%.1f", distanceInMiles) // round up

    distanceLabel.text = "\(roundUp) mi"

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This part is correct:

```
let distanceInMiles = distanceInMeters/1609.344  // distance in miles
```

Check distance in meters and compare with Google Maps.
If you are in `iOS 10` you can use new `Measurement` and related classes like this:

```
let meters = 1000.0

let distanceMeters = Measurement(value: meters, unit: UnitLength.meters)

let distanceMiles = distanceMeters.converted(to: UnitLength.miles)
let miles = distanceMeters.converted(to: UnitLength.miles).value
```

This code produces this results:
[image]

Comment: Hi, I just checked my distance in Meters and Kilometer and compared with Google Maps. I got different number. I am not sure where I did wrong when getting distance number?

Comment: Check the distance with exact coordinates for `location1` and `location2` on `iOS` and `Google Maps`

Comment: I just checked location1 and location2 coordinates. I think the coordinates showing on the google map is not so accurate. Because when I copy the exactly coordinates and applied on my app. I got 2.1 miles on my app. ( The same number I got on google map). But, the location1 (the location1 icon) and location2 (user's location) is not showing correct on my app. Is there any good way to check if I have correct coordinate?

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4 , XCode9

```
extension CLLocation {

    func myDistance(coordinate: CLLocation)->String{

        let distanceInMeters = self.distance(from: coordinate)

        if distanceInMeters < 1000 {
            return distanceInMeters.description + " M"
        }else{
            let distanceInKilometer = distanceInMeters /  1000
            return String(format:"%.1f", distanceInKilometer) + " KM"
        }

    }

}
```